# Can $U(\rho_1\otimes\rho_2)U^\dagger$ be entangled if either of $\rho_1$ or $\rho_2$ is a maximally mixed state?

Tags: entanglement, textbook-and-exercises

Given two qubit states $\rho_1$ and $\rho_2$. By applying some unitary $U$ we get $\rho = U(\rho_1 \otimes \rho_2)U^\dagger$. Can $\rho$ be entangled if either of $\rho_1$ or $\rho_2$ is a maximally mixed state?

Answer (score 2):

The question is equivalent to the following: can a balanced mixture of (not all separable) states be entangled?

To see the equivalence, observe that if $\rho_2=I/d$ ($d$ is here the dimension of the space) then
$$\rho=\frac1 d\sum_{k=1}^d U(\rho_1\otimes|k\rangle\langle k|)U^\dagger,$$
and if we don't put further restrictions on $U$ and $\rho_1$, then the only thing we know about $U(\rho_1\otimes |k\rangle\langle k|)U^\dagger$ is that they are orthogonal states (and if we are to hope the mixture is entangled, the states cannot be all separable).

This is not the case. As a counterexample in the two-qubit scenario, consider
$$
\sqrt2|\Phi_+\rangle \equiv |00\rangle + |11\rangle,
\qquad
\sqrt3|\Psi\rangle \equiv |00\rangle + |10\rangle - |11\rangle.
$$
You can then verify that $(|\Phi_+\rangle\!\langle\Phi_+|+|\Psi\rangle\!\langle\Psi|)/2$ is still entangled (using e.g. the PPT criterion).

Translated into the notation of the question, this example would correspond to $\rho_1=|0\rangle\langle 0|$ (or any other pure state), and $U$ such that $U|0,0\rangle=|\Phi_+\rangle$ and $U|0,1\rangle=|\Psi\rangle$.

This paper might be of interest to figure out when mixing pure *maximally entangled* states can result in an entangled state: ([Flores and Galapon 2016](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aop.2016.05.018)).